# How to print from a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

I have a dictionary:

```py
courses = {
    "Computer Science": [
        "Introduction to Programming",
        "Data Structures and Algorithms",
        "Operating Systems",
    ],
    "Mathematics": [
        "Calculus I",
        "Linear Algebra",
        "Differential Equations",
    ],
    "History": [
        "World History I",
        "World History II",
        "US History",
    ],
}
```

and I want to get the output as :

```
Computer Science: Introduction to Programming, Data Structures and Algorithms, Operating Systems

Mathematics: Calculus I, Linear Algebra, Differential Equations

History: World History I, World History II, US History
```

The data needed to be in a data-frame, that's sorted out, but is there any other way than using 2 for loops to print the expected result ?

I tried using lambdas, but still couldn't.
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

*What you expect is not clear.*

Are you looking for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(courses)
print(df.apply(lambda x: f"{x.name}: {', '.join(x)}\n").str.cat(sep='\n'))
```

Output:

```
Computer Science: Introduction to Programming, Data Structures and Algorithms, Operating Systems

Mathematics: Calculus I, Linear Algebra, Differential Equations

History: World History I, World History II, US History
```

With python only:

```
for k, v in courses.items():
    print(f"{k}: {', '.join(v)}", end='\n\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can python List Comprehension,

```
 "\n".join([k+":"+", ".join(courses[k]) for k in courses])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in courses.keys():
    print(i + ':', *courses[i])
```